# Ubuntu installation error: Error informing the kernel about modifications to partition -- Device or resource busy

Tags: system-installation

Error message:

> Error informing the kernel about modifications to partition /dev/sda1 -- Device or resource busy. This means Linux won’t know about any changes you made to /dev/sda1 until you reboot -- so you shouldn’t mount it or use it in any way before rebooting.

I get the same error when I go back and restart the installer.

Context:
I have a Windows 10 machine and I want to wipe Windows and install Ubuntu 22.04.03 LTS. I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oNEwEQ0uU1Y&t=253s

Comment: What does the bottom of the output of the `sudo dmesg` command show?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not sorted this already. Have you tried entering BIOS settings and turning off Secure boot for the installation process?

Worked for me with the same error.